# Multiprocessing issue on Windows 10

Tags: python, multiprocessing, windows-10, pool

I am trying to collect the size of homepages of a list of sites using multiprocessing. Following is the code :

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

start = time.time()


def sitesize(url):
    for url in sites:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
            page = u.read()
            print(url, len(page))


sites = [
    'https://www.yahoo.com',
    'http://www.cnn.com',
    'http://www.python.org',
    'http://www.jython.org',
    'http://www.pypy.org',
    'http://www.perl.org',
    'http://www.cisco.com',
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    'http://www.twitter.com',
    'http://arstechnica.com',
    'http://www.reuters.com',
    'http://www.abcnews.com',
    'http://www.cnbc.com',
]

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(sitesize, sites):
            print(result)

print(f'Time taken : {time.time() - start}')
```

I am having a Windows 10 laptop with Python 3.9 running. I am not using venv.

This code goes into a loop - executes 4 times and takes 4 times longer.

What is the error here ? Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how the `pool.imap_unordered` works, the provided function will be called with one of the values from the `sites`, whereas in your case you actually completely discard the provided `url` and loop on all values in the `sites`list.

You should simply do

```py
def sitesize(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        page = u.read()
        print(url, len(page))
```

See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map).

Comment: Thanks a lot - this solved it. The time is still not 1/4th but i think that is fine. It is approx 0.5 times, which is acceptable.

Comment: @Sachin D 1/4 runtime is not to be expected. With multiprocessing you get some additional overhead (inter-process communication, scheduling, locking/managing of shared resources like stdout and networking stacks).

Comment: Also, if you only need concurrency to do IO stuff, I recommend using multithreading instead, because your bottleneck is not CPU but IO. See this [nice tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/).

Answer (score -1):

Few issues:

```
def sitesize(url):
    result = {}
    for url in sites:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
            page = u.read()
            result[url] = len(page)
    return result
```

- sitesize does not return anything --> see above for what you need to have
- no need for the loop `for result in pool.imap_unordered(sitesize, sites):`
  -->  change to `result = pool.map(sitesize, sites)`

Comment: pool.imap_unordered(sitesize, sites) returns an iterator. If I remove the for loop, how will it return the result ?

Comment: why not using map instead?

Comment: Ok, are you suggesting that I should create a list using map ? I am not looking for that. I am simply looking at an output that prints the url and filesize. Without multiprocessing, the code is simple and runs in 11 sec on my machine. With multiprocessing as per my  code, takes 44 seconds and each url is run 4 times.

Comment: If you will go my way it will take 11/4 seconds since each core will take care of 1/4 of the URL list in the SAME time.

Comment: Tried both suggestions. The code returns a dictionary (as expected) of the url and filesize. But it takes nearly 72 seconds ...

Comment: The [documention of map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) actually states "_Consider using imap() or imap_unordered() with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency._"